# shutil.rmtree(...) does not work in my script

Tags: python, shutil

I try to delete a created directory in my destructor:

```
shutil.rmtree("C:\\projects\\project_alpha\\tmp")
```

It does not work with my python script but when I execute this command via python console it works and the tmp-directory will deleted.

Where is the difference?

Comment: What does "does not work" means? You get an error? You get no error and nothing is deleted?

Comment: Assuming that the issue is a __del__ method not being called my answer should help.  Otherwise you should post the relevant portions of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume by "destructor" you mean the `__del__` method.

From [the docs on **del**](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

> It is not guaranteed that **del**() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

What you might want to do is register an [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) handler.

For example at module level:

```
import atexit

def cleanup_directories():
    directories = ["C:\\projects\\project_alpha\\tmp",]
    for path in directories:
        if os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path):
            shutil.rmtree(path)

atexit.register(cleanup_directories)
```

Functions registered with atexit will be run when the interpreter exits regardless of how the interpreter exits.

Of course, you could also do something hacky like force the garbage collector to run (`import gc; gc.collect()`, which may force your **del** method to run but I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that's a bad idea.

;-)